# Create a controller and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello I have the following models.

The User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_one :user_informations
  has_secure_password
end
```

The UserInformation Model:

```
class UserInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :address, :address2, :business, :descripcion, :identification_number, :mobile_cell, :name, :phone_number
end
```

Now I need to create the view and the controller to create and update the user information, and I have many questions:

1) how can I generate the controller:

> rails g controller UserInformations

o

> rails g controller UserInformation

2) how my new, create and update action know the user ID.

3) how can I set the routes for this user information

Thanks. Maybe these are a basic question, but I'm new in rails and I don't know how to do all of this.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have to use pluralize for controller, so `rails g controller UserInformations` will work.

2 + 3) You can set up Restful routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'user_information'
  end
end
```

With above routes you will have path `users/:id/user_information`, so you can know your user ID through `params[:id]`, ex, in your create or update action you can use:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
```

to find which user is shown informaton.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a user_id column in your user_information table and model.

1) rails g UserController

2) you can include the user_id as param, so for the new action it will be

```
def new
  @user = User.find(param[:user_id])
  @user_information = @user.user_information.new
end
```

the create and update actions would get the user id from the form params but you'll need to think about who is going to be using these actions and if you want to allow all users to update the information of other users. If not, you should have the user id as a hidden param and use a gem like cancan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to restrict access

alternatively you can set them up as nested resources (http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources)

3) for a simple resources you can add this to your routes.rb file

```
resource :user_information
```

or for nested you can do

```
resource :users do
  member do
    resource :user_information
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all

in User Model, there should be

```
  has_one :user_information
```

as there association name should be singular with has_one.

you can create controller by giving the command

```
rails g controller UserInformation
```

and it depends on you what name you want to give to you controller.

In new action you will have to find user by its id. You can store user id in session
after login. Or if you are saving user first time then you will have to pass user id.

In new action do

```
user = User.find(session[:id])
user.user_information.create(params[:user_information])
```

I think you need to study all this first. Go through some examples. Then try. It is too quick to ask here.

Comment: Thnaks Akshay Vishnoi but I have a question about the controller, in the rails controller convention said that the controllers are plurals, so I don't know the controllers should be rails g controller UserInformations or rails generate controller UsersInformation. Thanks

Comment: you should use controller names plurals actually. It helps in routes.
As for index action we can use directly user_information_path.
So in your case go with  "rails g controller user_informations"

Comment: also if you will provide action name in generate command, rails will automatically generate action methods and views for you.
for e.g. rails g controller user_informations index, new, edit